# Android layout qualifiers

Tags: android, android-layout

I currently work on an application which has to support different screen sizes. I read through the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) about this and decided to create different layout with the smallest width qualifier. The documentations notes:

> **smallestWidth - `sw<N>dp`** The smallestWidth is a fixed screen size characteristic of the device; the device's smallestWidth does not change when the screen's orientation changes.
>
> **Available width -  `w<N>dp`** This configuration value will change when the orientation changes between landscape and portrait to match the current actual width.

I did so and everything works great but nevertheless I am a bit confused: Due to [device metrics](https://material.io/devices/) the Google Pixel should have a minimum width of 411 dp. In my application I created a layout with the `sw480dp` qualifier but when I select the Pixel device from the Android Studio layout editor it always opens the normal layout without qualifier.

I also tried to create my own hardware profile for the Galaxy S6 (360 dp) through the AVD manager but it faces the same problem. Have I missunderstood something here?

I also do not quite understand this image from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali). How do I have to read it? The `small`, `medium`, etc. qualifier are deprecated so why are they in there or is this only used for conversions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my application I created a layout with the sw480dp qualifier but when I select the Pixel device from the Android Studio layout editor it always opens the normal layout without qualifier.

411 is less than 480. Hence, `-sw480dp` is not a valid qualifier.

> Have I missunderstood something here?

The `NNN` value in `-swNNNdp` is the lower bound, not the upper bound. Devices with a smallest width of `NNNdp` *or larger* would use `-sw480dp`.

> How do I have to read it?

I have no idea what information that image is supposed to be conveying.

Comment: _Is the lower bound_ thank you for this. But isn't this a bit inconvenient? With an upper bound I definitely know how large my views can get and therefore set them to exact dp sizes which fit the layout. With a lower bound I do not have these information unless I have another greater qualifier.

Comment: @Cilenco: "With an upper bound I definitely know how large my views can get and therefore set them to exact dp sizes which fit the layout" -- IMHO, try to minimize the use of exact sizes.

Comment: Due to my layout I can't (I did amap): I use the new [circle positioning](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CircularPositioning) from the ConstraintLayout. My center view is an ImageView with `dimensionRatio="1:1"` which fills the whole layout (with some padding) and I think the `circleRadius` only takes dp values. Would you recommend to use another layout for this?

Comment: @Cilenco: "I think the circleRadius only takes dp values" -- it should take any dimension unit, though `dp` is a good choice of unit. "Would you recommend to use another layout for this?" -- beats me. I have not used circular positioning.